# Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055

Tags: webdriver

I am a newbie with webdriver and need some help..

I am using Selenium 2.2.0  with FF v7.0.1 on Windows XP

I've managed to record and play back a java script successfully in IE but whenever I try and execute the same script in FF, I get the following error message:

Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms

I've read at numbe of places that if I downgrade the firefox version to 3.6 script will work fine however I am not to keen on downgrading. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
package hisScripts;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class WebdriverTest_1 {
private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://**********/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'my profile')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'about the service')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'contact us')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'help')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'home')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'logout')]")).click();

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
        fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
}

private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(by);
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The code is ok. What about upgrading? From FF7 to, say, FF9 or 10? Selenium can't work well with FF11 (so far), but the FF9 works fine!

Comment: @slanec - I've upgraed to FFv10.0.2 but still no joy - iS there anything else I could do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The selenium version you are using is extremely old. I don't think firefox 10 is supported in v2.2. The latest is 2.20.

Take a look at change log [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/CHANGELOG). From the notes here native events in firefox 10 were supported starting from v2.19.0 that means you would need 2.19 or higher to support firefox 10.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out..

It turned out to be silly mistake where I assumed selenium 2.2.0 is
same as Selenium 2.20.0.

To correct the problem I downloaded the latest 'Server' and 'Client
drivers' (Java in my case) from http://seleniumhq.org/download/ and
guess what it worked great :)

Comment: In a Rails environment, this may mean upgrading the selenium-server jar used for running the remote server as well as upgrading the gem used by the server. I had the latter up-to-date but forgot that the former also needed upgrading.

Comment: I had a similar problem with version 2.24.X. So i changed to 2.25.0. Thank you.

Comment: For firefox 29.0 i changed to selenium driver 2.39.0

Answer (score -1):

This problem is due to the compatibility of fire fox version and the selenium jar file version.Use the latest selenium jar files.that can fix the problem.