# Java Constructor Parameters Selenium Versus WebDriverBackedSelenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am working with an older version of an automation script that logs into a page and runs tests.

We want to change the classic selenium constructor to a WebDriverBackedSelenium constructor in order to do some more involved testing.

Our original constructor call was:

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "https://asdffdsa.com/");
```

How do I set the WebDriverBackedSelenium constructor with the same parameters? The API shows that we need to set the constructor as:

```
seWebDriver = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "https://asdffdsa.com");
```

There doesn't seem to be any indication about where the selenium server is running, what port, and what browser.

Currently using the following code:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    seWebDriver = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "https://www.asdfdfdfsfs.com");

    seWebDriver.open("/");
```

Just now noticing that I'm getting the following error:

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
*** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded**
 LOG addons.xpi: startup
 **LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share**
 LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /var/folders/pf/hvzyf38x59vfbgf8zpvw5v800000gn/T/anonymous2501560210712840923webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
 **LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges**
 LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening database
 **LOG addons.xpi-utils: Creating database schema**
 LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
 **Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled**
 LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
 **LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons**
 LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
 **LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list**
 LOG addons.manager: shutdown
 **LOG addons.xpi: shutdown**
 LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
 **LOG addons.xpi-utils: Database closed**
 LOG addons.xpi: startup
 **LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share**
 LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /var/folders/pf/hvzyf38x59vfbgf8zpvw5v800000gn/T/anonymous2501560210712840923webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
 **LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found

Comment: dude, look at my answer below. instead of using driver = new FirefoxDriver() use a driver = new RemoteWebDriver(hub, capabilities) where hub is something like http://localhost:4444/wd/hub. I don't understand why you'd edit the question when I already provided the answer. Also, the selenium documentation is pretty good, all of this stuff is answered there.

Comment: The error that I was getting as listed above was due to versioning incomaptibilities or something. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013898/unable-to-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-on-port-7055 for more information on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for using Webdriver backed selenium.

There will be no need to mention the port number while using webdriverbacked Selenium.

In the below program, the object `Selenium` is for utilising the properties of Selenium RC(your old automation script constructor).

The object `driver`  is for utilising the features of Webdriver (Selenium2.0).

```
public class BackedWebdriver {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String baseUrl;
    public static Selenium selenium;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();    //Here we are mentioning that we will use Firefox browser
        baseUrl = "http://www.google.co.in/";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
        selenium.windowMaximize();
        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("selenium");
        selenium.click("g");
        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb")).click();


    }
```

Comment: I think we need the features of Webdriver in this automation, but when I set this up and run it as a UnitTest, it's trying to load localhost instead of the site that I gave it in the constructor.

Comment: Are you using driver.get(url)  or selenium.open(url) ?
It would be helpful if you can share the code.

Comment: selenium.open(url) code is a mess I'mma try to clean it up a bit and post the relevant parts up.

Answer (score 0):

```
DesiredCapabilities ffLinux = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
ffLinux.setBrowserName("firefox");
ffLinux.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);
String hubLocation = http://yourmachine.com:4444/wd/hub;
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(hubLocation, ffLinux);
driver.get(yourWebApplicationURLThatsBeingTested);
```

In your example above with the WebDriverBackedSelenium, the first parameter you passed in was "driver". Look at how I set up my WebDriver above: it specifies the hub location.